# sbt complains about JmhPlugin not found

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-jmh

I'm trying to use sbt JmhPlugin and I'm following the instructions found here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jmh

So I added the plugin to `project/plugins.sbt` and then I added to `build.sbt` the `enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)` line so my build files look like this:

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.4.4")
```

project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version = 1.8.2
```

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "myproj"
  )
libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.15"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "2.5.3"

val catsVersion = "2.9.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % catsVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % catsVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-laws" % catsVersion
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-mtl-core" % "0.7.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "simulacrum" % "1.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalamacros" %% "resetallattrs" % "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.22"
libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "discipline-munit" % "1.0.6"

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-language:_",
  "-Ymacro-annotations"
)


enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

but when I'm running `sbt build` it complains that it cannot find the `JmhPlugin`:

```
error: not found: value JmhPlugin
enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
^
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, how should I debug this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you reloaded your **sbt** session after making the changes?

Comment: Yes. It's a fresh call to `sbt compile` each time

Comment: Uhm, maybe is it related to your weird mix between using global settings and module settings? Try moving everything side the `root` _project_, or try just removing that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Even with the "weird mix" fixed it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

Using this `build.sbt` file on an empty project it seems to at least resolve the dependencies:

```scala
name := "myproj"
version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.2.15",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % "test",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-effect" % "2.5.3",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "2.9.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-free" % "2.9.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-laws" % "2.9.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "cats-mtl-core" % "0.7.1",
  "org.typelevel" %% "simulacrum" % "1.0.1",
  "org.scalamacros" %% "resetallattrs" % "1.0.0",
  "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.22",
  "org.typelevel" %% "discipline-munit" % "1.0.6"
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-language:_",
  "-Ymacro-annotations"
)

enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

Comment: This behaves the same on my machine.

Comment: @vidi then it is a networking problem or something with your computer set up, it is impossible for ur to help.

Comment: The computer was fine. I'm 100% sure it was something else but I didn't investigate further and I just didn't use the JmhPlugin anymore
Thanks for trying to help!